# Is it possible to concat_ws many columns in hive SQL?

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
select
    concat_ws(',', collect_list(cast(col1 as string))) as col1_list,
    concat_ws(',', collect_list(cast(col2 as string))) as col2_list,
    concat_ws(',', collect_list(cast(col3 as string))) as col3_list,
    concat_ws(',', collect_list(cast(col4 as string))) as col4_list
    -- about 100 columns here to concat_ws
from
    table
group by
    id
```

I run the hive table, the yarn always raise error although I increase the memory size, `attempt_1619436551724_1645902_4_01_000014_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

If I dont use `concat_ws` statement, I can run the hive table sucessfully. If it `concat_ws` need much memory?

Comment: List can be big. concat_ws requires even more memory because in addition to list it produces concatenated string, both in memory in the same container. The question is how to increase memory?

Comment: Thank U. I just want to make sure the operation is OK. I'll follow your suggestion and try again with more memory.

Comment: Try to find out ID s with too many rows and consider processing them separately if  there is huge skew in ID distribution